# Is protobuf.js able to read from stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, protobuf.js

I'm new to `Node.js`. Currently I have a binary file, which contains lots of protobuf `Message`. I don't know how to separate them. I also don't understand what `Reader` is here in `Message.decodeDelimited(reader: Reader|Uint8Array): Message` mentioned in protobuf document.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var buffer = fs.readFileSync('protobufBinaryFile');
var message = Message.decodeDelimited(buffer);
```

But I can only get the first message.

Comment: Got the answer from here: https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/issues/855.